# Fail to locate first-child and last-child at the same time using styled component

Tags: css, reactjs, styled-components

Just play around styled component recently and just wonder why I cannot use `first-child` and `last-child` at the same time which I can apply similar concepts when I using SCSS

What I want to do is to have customized style based on whether they are the first or last child of `RowWrapper` but no luck. Just want to know whether I have missed some concepts? Thank you very much in advance.

Reference link:

1. sandbox [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/damp-dew-bnqov) using styled component
2. Testing [link](https://codepen.io/cheukfungtse/pen/BaNgZae) using SCSS

```
const RowWrapper = styled.div`

  :first-child {
    border: solid 1px black;
    color: red;
  }

  :last-child {
    border: solid 1px red;
    color: green;

    span {
      font-size: 22px;
    }
  }
`;
`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're applying the pseudo-classes to the `RowWrapper` component itself. To apply them to the children, prepend a `>`:

```
const RowWrapper = styled.div`
  >:first-child {
    border: solid 1px black;
    color: red;
  }

  >:last-child {
    border: solid 1px red;
    color: green;

    span {
      font-size: 22px;
    }
  }
`;
```

Comment: is there any difference when applying css rules between scss and styled-components? Coz I am adapting almost the same rules on the above demo links.

Comment: I don't know, I have never used SCSS.